# Location auto complete in HTML SERVICE not working with Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

I am trying the below mentioned example in Apps Script HTML UI , But its not working

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1

Please assist. I want a Location  text field with  autocomplete/suggestion of places.

Comment: show your code that is not working. Generally, apis like these do not work  from htmlservice.

If the code is being removed by caja, you could use a pure html web page communicating with a GAS using content service

Comment: you will find the code in the above link

Comment: YOUR code! You do not show what is not working. Read the guidelines for stackoverflow

Comment: When i execute this code as an html service it throws an error

Comment: Invalid script or HTML content: HtmlOutput:56+1 - 2: Expected <Selector> not } HtmlOutput:56+1 - 2: Skipping malformed content https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places:13+3 - 15+4: Properties cannot end in "__": Rule "setBadSuffix", AssignOperation : ASSIGN SpecialOperation :